# Jenkins after pod kill remembers all configuration but cannot pull repo from git

Tags: jenkins, gitea

I have setup a Jenkins and Gitea. What I am facing now is that when I kill the Jenkins pod, it comes back up with all configuration and build history. But for some reason it is not able to pull git repo when called by the webhook on commit I get:

(Jenkins Organization can pull new info about repos I add in Gitea. Also when I recreate the organization folder or pipeline in Jenkins, it sudenly starts working fine.)

```
Gitea] Notifying branch build status: PENDING Build started...
[Gitea] Notified
Looking up repository Home/dhcp-repo
Querying the current revision of branch main...
Current revision of branch main is a6cc72ed61bb71b7e731558f2103b8c79faf8aa7
Obtained Jenkinsfile from a6cc72ed61bb71b7e731558f2103b8c79faf8aa7
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on UB02 in /mnt/data/jenkins/workspace/Home_dhcp-repo_main
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Checkout SCM)
[Pipeline] checkout
The recommended git tool is: NONE
using credential root
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from http://git.admin.net/Home/dhcp-repo.git
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:999)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1241)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1305)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:136)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:101)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:88)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git config remote.origin.url http://git.admin.net/Home/dhcp-repo.git" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: not in a git directory

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2846)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2766)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2761)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommand(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2051)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommand(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2063)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.setRemoteUrl(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1662)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.setRemoteUrl(GitAPI.java:180)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler$RPCRequest.perform(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:924)
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler$RPCRequest.call(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:902)
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler$RPCRequest.call(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:853)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:211)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:54)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:377)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService.lambda$wrap$0(InterceptingExecutorService.java:78)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
    Suppressed: hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to UB02
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1787)
        at hudson.remoting.UserRequest$ExceptionResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:356)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:1003)
        at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:285)
        at jdk.proxy55/jdk.proxy55.$Proxy137.setRemoteUrl(Unknown Source)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl.setRemoteUrl(RemoteGitImpl.java:348)
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:987)
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1241)
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1305)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:136)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:101)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:88)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
ERROR: Maximum checkout retry attempts reached, aborting
[Pipeline] }
```

Thanks in advance for advices....

I have tried to add deleteDir() to Jenkinsfile with no chages in results. Also I have tried to pull the repo on the agent manually and had no issues.